# When one's asked about contract rate, is it ever OK to do any of the following

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

- Put it back to the employer first by asking what they are thinking of offering before answering?
- State a rate but also say that it is negotiable?  And if so should a % for negotiation ever be stated?
- State a rate but say that you're really keen on the job and can "adjust" as needed?

Comment: Your first question seems to mostly be answered in [Does the first person to mention a number in a salary negotiation lose?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/183) Your second and third questions seem like different versions of the same thing and are answered in [Is it okay to write 'negotiable' next to the desired salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/78760)

Comment: this is a q about contract rates not FTE employment which every one who has answered seems to have missed

Answer (score 0):

> is it ever OK to do any of the following

Yes to all. They are all valid negotiation techniques.

Which to use depends on the nature of that offer you are negotiating, and if you see if there is actually room or chance to bargain in such ways.

**Asking them first is usually the most recommended thing to do**, so they can give you a number and you either agree with it or try to bargain up. However, recruiters may evade this move and ask you again, insisting *you* give them a number first (Game Theory usually backs you up here, try reading [Does the First person to mention a Number in Salary Negotiation lose?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183/does-the-first-person-to-mention-a-number-in-a-salary-negotiation-lose)).

Stating your offer first may be more recommended when you consider having a better knowledge on the average salaries in that specific industry, or when you have no choice because they insist on you stating it first. You can also try this if you do have some valuable asset to leverage that most surely help the company and justify that price you ask for.

But even though I would always prefer for them to name a price first (sometimes you may end up hearing more than you thought or expected), it is also recommended to wait for them to bring the money questions first.

Comment: This is SO helpful, DarkCygnus!  I was feeling rather stupid asking the question so am surprised and very much helped..  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped @SLim :) consider upvoting when you can if you found this useful. I also suggest you wait for other answers before deciding which one to accept. Just a last comment, it is always useful if you know the average salaries anyways, so in case they give you an offer you can actually know if it is good or not.

Comment: You should normally never up front say its negotiable so 2 and 3 I would say you should not do

Comment: DarkCygnus - I've upvoted but because I just joined today it's too new for them to let the system to reflect it publicly, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... here's what I do.  I do my research, look at typicals for the position and my experience.  I examine how much I'm making now, and bump it up a notch in my head.  Then I decide what I want.  **This is key; you have to go into the negotiation knowing what you want to get out of it.**  At that point, I can say to prospective employer or recruiter, "Here's the number I like; can you beat it?"

I like to move first, because if I wait for the other party, I'm afraid that they'll become ... set ... in their number before I can influence it.

Update after comments:

It's not unreasonable to talk rates before interviews as a filtering function for both sides.  Hiring types have **some** latitude, but if they're prepared to offer say 20-30/hr and you are asking 50, you both can save a lot of time.  Interviews are **expensive** to you and to the hiring company, in terms of opportunity cost and general distraction.  When I was a contractor, I talked to my or corporate recruiters about general ranges way before any interviews.

Comment: this is a contract rate not a fulltime job negotiation  you need to account for you self employed taxes and void times when your not working

Comment: Good thoughts akaioi and Neuromancer.  I think a lot of it depends on how much one would want the job.  I'm surprised they asked the rate before we've had an interview!  Maybe that's their first level of filtering...

Comment: @SLim added some more thoughts after reading comments